# SQL "with" clause - Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query which works fine:

```
select a.dataId, a.my_no,  b.my_attribute  from myDB.table_a a left join myDB.table_b b 
on a.my_no = b.my_no order by dataId
```

However, if I include the `with` clause like below:

```
with my_table as (
    select a.dataId, a.my_no,  b.my_attribute  from myDB.table_a a left join myDB.table_b b 
    on a.my_no = b.my_no order by dataId
)

select * from my_table
```

I got the following error:

```
Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.
```

This is confusing ... shouldn't these two queries be identical? What did I do wrong here? (I am using MariaDB server) Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Before a `WITH` clause, you should specify the database you're using with

```
USE db_name;
```

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

just do:

```
select * from myDB.my_table
```

works as well.

Comment: this works for me

Answer (score 1):

That might happen because you have more schemas in your connection. Maybe a database version of the staging/production or other environment. What you can do , is, you right click on the schema that you want to have it as default, and click on `Set as Default Schema`, now every query that would need the information about a schema, will use the one that you set as default.

I faced the issue when I was trying to run a query

```
select distinct(status) from inventory_locations;
```

But then I was getting the following error:

```
Error Code: 1046. No database selected....
```

One option would be to do:

```
select distinct(status) from `schema_name`.inventory_locations;
```

where the `schema_name` is the name of the schema that you imported.

Or just do what I said in the beginning.
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The difference?  Look closely:

```
select ... myDB.table_a ...

with            table_a ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open your MYSQLWorkbench
2. write this USE databaseName, in your example it becomes like that
   USE myDB.table_a then enter,

then start writing normal queries

Answer (score -2):

create ur own database in
MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode
as create a new database(name)
after that use it in your MySQL Workbench

for example :
you create a database as parth in (MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode)

after that go to workbench and type on the first line
USE parth;

and type ur all codes it will work:-